# Android list view with custom row layout issue

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I Have a ListView and a SimpleCursorAdapter, also im using custom row_layout for displaying my items.
my problem is that i want to set an item click listener to each item in the listview and then get the values that displayed.

this is the custom row layout , i have only 2 items : textview for name and another textview for ID (which is invisibile).
im doing that because i want to extract the whole item from the database so i need to compare the ID

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/product_id_id" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>"

    <TextView android:id="@+id/product_name_id" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

how i can get the TextView value that is invisible which representing my ID ?

within this method

```
 @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

              // ListView Clicked item index
              int itemPosition = position;

              // ListView Clicked item value
              String  itemValue   = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

              Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProductViewActivity.class);
              intent.putExtra("product",itemValue);
              startActivityForResult(intent, PRODUCT_REQUEST_ID);
             }

          });
```

Comment: you can use the arraylist that u may be using to populate your listView

Comment: You have to create a model class, like a view holder class to store the two textview's values. Check tutorials

Comment: could you give me a link to one?

Comment: you need to see below link, its very usefull
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html